# load parent scope before child scope using angular ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am using angularjs and the angular ui router to load nested templates.  The child's controller inherits the parent's $scope for it's contents.  This is all working fine except when I try to load the child scope as the initial view, the child scope is empty.

www.domain.com/products - parent view - works
www.domain.com/products/product-child view - works when navigating from parent.

When I try to load www.domain.com/products/product directly, the child template appears to load before the parent is complete leaving the child scope empty.

Here is the ui router info.

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider
  .state('products', {
    url: "/products",
    templateUrl: "/views/products.html",
    controller: "ProductsCtrl"
  })

  .state('products.product', {
    url: "/:description",
    templateUrl: "/views/product.html",
    controller: "ProductCtrl"
  })
});
```

What am I missing?

Parent View:

```
<section class="product-container">

  <a ui-sref="products.product({description:product.description})" ng-repeat="product in     products | orderBy : orderObjectBy(products,'active',true)" class="product" ng-click="" ng-     class="{inactive:!filterProducts(product, products.keywords) && isFilterChecked() , 'selected-    product':(product.selected)}" ng-style="{left: ((product.pos_left*360) + 'px'),top: ((product.pos_top*360) + 'px')}">

    <img ng-src="http://www.tiempotimepiece.com/catalog/{{product.SmallImageUrl}}">
    <p>{{product.description}}</p>
    {{product.price | currency}}
    <p>{{product.order}}</p>

  </a>

  <div ui-view></div>

</section>
```

Child View:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in items | filter: {description:description}">
  Sku:{{product.Sku}}<br>
  IdProduct:{{product.IdProduct}}<br>
  price:{{product.price}}<br>
  description:{{product.description}}<br>
  SmallImageUrl:{{product.SmallImageUrl}}<br>
</div>
```

The child controller inherits the parent $scope by using $scope.$parent.  When loading the child view as the initial page, the child view/controller appears to load before the parent has completed populating the scope.

What am I missing here?  Thanks!

UPDATE: I do think a service is the quickest fix here and probably the best solution, but I am adding links to the Gists of the two controllers if anybody is interested in looking into this further to see if that is the best approach.  These are a work in progress and have not been refactired at all and are frankly a mess at this point.  There is a lot of crazy filtering and sorting going on.

Products (Parent) : https://gist.github.com/bennewton999/8257080

Product (Child) : https://gist.github.com/bennewton999/8257058

Comment: So possible sidestep, why are you calling $scope.parent?  Would it be possible to change your child controller to get the object without it?  I feel like what you really want is a Products service that can either get all products for /products, or a single product for /products/product, so you don't have to rely on parent.

Comment: I suppose that's a possibility. It just seemed logical to use the parent scope since it's already available. But if it is really not available on initial load, I guess I should reconsider that approach.

Comment: I would consider using a service for exactly the situation you've having trouble with; if a child view can't be loaded without a parent, then you're prescribing that it must have a parent, but that's not true if they can hit the product page directly.  Sorry I don't know the real answer to your question, but I would recommend using a [Service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) to serve the data to both views instead.

Comment: That's fine though, the child view always has a parent because of how it is defined and the parent state will be setup before the child state. Could you post your controller code maybe? You should never really access $scope.parent, and just rely on the prototypical inheritance. You need to provide more code for me to tell what's actually going on.\

Comment: I think you're right @Hylianpuffball, I should just call the service in the child view and then it will work.  Friday afternoon is not the best time to be rushing through something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I came in Monday morning with a fresh mind and realized I didn't need a different controller for this view at all.  I just changed the controller to use the products controller for the product view and that was it.